# How to play html audio in android Webview ,I need simple coding

Tags: android

Basically I am new in Android development , HTML audio is not playing in Android Webview .Can someone help me out. I am using Java.
Thank you

Comment: http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - thanks - you're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line with your code:

```
webSettings.setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
```